# JSON_OBJECT on int value doesnt work-mysql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to do this on mysql -

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id',id_question,'ques',question,'yes',count yes,'no',count no)
 FROM ( SELECT * FROM `covid19-db`.`Survey data` WHERE `approved`=1) 
 as T;
```

but it doesnt work becuse `count yes` is int.
is there a soultion?

Answer (score 0):

If your column name contains a space, you must enclose them in back-ticks:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', id_question, 'ques', question, 'yes', `count yes`, 'no', `count no`)
FROM ( SELECT * FROM `covid19-db`.`Survey data` WHERE `approved`=1) AS T;
```

I try to avoid defining column names with spaces for this reason. I use `_` as an easy alternative.